# ([Bug Theme) headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/30/d516325486/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/dimsemenov-Touchfolio

Tags: wordpress

I am a noob and since month I try to fix these bug but I understand nothing... Somebody can help me ?

https://imgshare.io/images/2020/03/11/Capturedd.png

medialibrary-uploader.php on line 125 : -

```
  // If we've got a post, loop through and get it's ID.
                if ( count( $_posts ) ) {
                    $_id = $_posts->ID;
                } else {
```

What can I do to fix my theme ? Maybe it's because a plugnin made a problem ?

Comment: Are you uising any redirect to another url using your code?

Answer (score 0):

**headers already sent** this error generally comes when there is any error in your code at somewhere.

try to Enable error reporting to locate your errored code and fix it.

Comment out this line

```
// define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

And add below code in your config.php file to enable more detailed error log.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```